# How can I create a macro in an Excel project

Tags: excel, vba

1. I have a web application that generates two different Excel reports with different numbers of leaves and different number of columns, see below.

   **Report 1**
   Sheet1 has four columns headed C11, C12, C13, C14
   Sheet2 has three columns headed C21, C22, C23

   **Report 2**
   Sheet1 has four columns headed C11, C12, C13, C14 (same as in Report 1)
   Sheet2 has three columns headed C21, C22, C23 (same as in Report 1)
   Sheet3 has three columns headed C31, C32, C33, C34, C35,....
2. I want to be able to remove some columns in the reports of two levels that I should enter, see below:

   **Level 1**: Search for Sheet1 and remove the C12 and then
   Search for Sheet2 and remove C22, then
   Search Sheet3, and remove C32

   **Level 2**: Search for Sheet1 and remove the C11 and C13, then
   Search for Sheet2 and remove the C21 and C22, then
   Search Sheet3, and remove C33, C34, C35
3. I want the macro first asks for the level and then searches for each Sheet and looking forward for each column and remove it as described above.

Comment: Are the column headers always going to be in the first row of each sheet?

Comment: VBA is not VB6.  Mistagged question.

Comment: Hi dash!
 No, they will be in row 6.
 Hope you can help me.

 best regards

Comment: Do you want the entire column to be deleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code. Run the Macro 'Choose' to select the level. This code deletes the entire column where the conditions are true

```
Sub Choose()
    l = InputBox(Prompt:="Enter the level you want", Title:="Level Selection")
    If l = 1 Then
        Call Level1
    ElseIf l = 2 Then
        Level2
    ElseIf l = "" Then
    Else
        MsgBox "Incorrect entry.", vbInformation, "Incorrect"
    End If
End Sub

Sub Level1()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    On Error Resume Next
    Blad1.Activate
    Blad1.Cells.Find(What:="C12", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    i = ActiveCell.Column
    Blad1.Columns(i).Delete

    Blad2.Activate
    Blad2.Cells.Find(What:="C22", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    i = ActiveCell.Column
    Blad2.Columns(i).Delete

    Blad3.Activate
    Blad3.Cells.Find(What:="C32", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    i = ActiveCell.Column
    Blad3.Columns(i).Delete
    Blad1.Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub


Sub Level2()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    On Error Resume Next
    Blad1.Activate
    Blad1.Cells.Find(What:="C11", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    i = ActiveCell.Column
    Blad1.Columns(i).Delete
    Blad1.Cells.Find(What:="C13", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    i = ActiveCell.Column
    Blad1.Columns(i).Delete

    Blad2.Activate
    Blad2.Cells.Find(What:="C21", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    i = ActiveCell.Column
    Blad2.Columns(i).Delete
    Blad2.Cells.Find(What:="C22", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    i = ActiveCell.Column
    Blad2.Columns(i).Delete

    Blad3.Activate
    Blad3.Cells.Find(What:="C33", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    i = ActiveCell.Column
    Blad3.Columns(i).Delete
    Blad3.Cells.Find(What:="C34", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    i = ActiveCell.Column
    Blad3.Columns(i).Delete
    Blad3.Cells.Find(What:="C35", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    i = ActiveCell.Column
    Blad3.Columns(i).Delete
    Blad1.Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Please [see the file](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B3mN8H2AV4UCMWIyMzgxYzMtZTZkNi00ZWM0LTkxZGUtOTA0OTI1ZGM0Nzdl) including macro

Comment: Many thanks Kannan for your help!
Now I tested macros and it ask for the Level, but then nothing happens. Why?
 best regards

Comment: In the prompt you have to enter the level you want. Enter 1 or 2 in the input box. Then click OK. On clicking OK it will delete the colums where the specified condition is present.

Comment: Instead of running the macro Choose, you can directly run Level1 or Level2 macro.

Comment: Can you explain on how you are using this. Do as following. Make sure that macro is enabled. Press Alt + F11. Enter the code given in a module. Run the macro Choose by clicking Alt + F8

Comment: Sorry Kannan for the inconvenience! I've copied the code into a module and tested it in two ways. First I connected macro to a button and when I click on it asks for the level and I tested with both 1 and 2, but it does not happen anything. Second I run the code directly into the Microsoft Visual Basic (v. 6.3) after I clicked on Alt + F11 and tested by clicking Alt + F8, same thing nothing happens. (I have Excel 2007 Swedish). Can I send you my Excelfile?

Comment: The codes above works only with excel. You have to give the code directly in excel. You can send me the excel file. Upload it somewhere and give the link here.

Comment: I meant VB available in excel, not VB as Separate applications. Here is the link to my test file
http://d01.megashares.com/dl/66b5ef2/Makro1.xlsx
Best regards

Comment: I have attached a sample file in the answer. Use that and try. Make sure that you enable macros for the file to work.

Comment: I apologize for all that is asked of you. It's actually the same, I write 1 or 2 as a level and click OK, but nothing is erased.

Comment: Did you try with the sample file provided. The code is supposed to delete columns. In level1 it will delete columns that contain C12 in sheet1, C22 in sheet2 and C32 in sheet3.

Comment: yes, I have tested the example that you have in your link above. Does it work with you?

Comment: Ok friend, there was a change. The code was for sheets named Sheet1, Sheet2 etc. Now it is changed as per the name that you have given. Try now and it will work. Please inform if it works. Sample file is also updated. You can check with that.

Comment: THANK YOU:):)
It works fine!!!
Wish you a very merry Christmas.
(Can I contact you by email if I have a question?)

Comment: Hey, who down voted this? When someone down votes please give the reason so that we can understand the mistake.